# How to find out additional information about burned CD or DVD disk?

Tags: security, dvd, compact-disc

For instance, some music is burned on CD/DVD disk. How to find out what program this disk was burned with? What kind of extra information CD/DVD stores? Is it possible to track down a PC which was recorded this disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using ISOBUSTER, this will give you all kinds of info, im not sure if it will give you the info you want but it shows a lot more in depth info than most. You can get an evaluation copy off the website which should do for the info you want to find out.

http://www.isobuster.com/